# To find an element in center

Tags: group-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity

Let $G$ be a group given by multiplication table. We are also given an $a \in G$. To check that $a \in C(G)$, i.e. in the center of $G$.

One easiest way is for all elements $b \in G$ check whether $a.b = b.a$. But this requires $n-1$ many operations ( $a.b = b.a$ ). Is there any efficient ( less no of operations ) way to do this?

Comment: Well, actually $n/2$ operations suffice (due to Lagrange).

Comment: @jbvee Are you referring to Lagrange's theorem? This would tell us that the center has size at most $n/2$ (provided it is not $G$) since it must divide the order of the group. I don't think this helps with the OP's question. Perhaps I don't see your argument.

Comment: @jpvee Really? I feel there are no efficient way to check whether an element is central only with multiplication table (i.e., without any further information, like inverses, power maps, conjugacy classes, generators, etc.).

Comment: @BryanCurtis and Orat: If $a$ commutes with $n/2$ group elements as well as with $a$ itself, then $|C_G(a)|>n/2$ and thus by Lagrange, $C_G(a)=G$ or, equivalently, $a$ lies in the center of $G$. (The question was not to determine the center of $G$ but the check whether a given element is central).

Comment: @jpvee I see (I wonder why I couldn't see that?). A bit better bound is $n/p$ where $p$ is the smallest prime divisor of $n$. (But finding such $p$ may cost.)

Comment: @jpvee But it still requires $n-1$ operations to check whether $a$ commutes with $n/2$ group elements. Or I just need to check commutivity with first $n/2$ elements?

Comment: @Don: Well, that depends on what exactly is meant by "operations". My understanding from your comment ("$a.b=b.a$") was that you considered the comparison of the two products as **one** operation and your other comment (_for all elements $b\in G$_) that you hadn't taken Lagrange into account - if I was mistaken there, I'll withdraw my initial comment. Either way, my guess was that you were looking for something more effective than a mere reduction by a factor $2$ anyway, so I had posted my comment without the intention to a solution to your original problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know a generating set $X$ for $G$, then it is sufficient to test whether  $ax=xa$ for all $x \in X$. Since any finite group $G$ has a generating set of size at most $\log_2 |G|$, this potentially reduces the number of checks to $O(\log |G|)$.

But if you are not given a generating set, then it will take at least $O(|G|)$ operations to find one (IIRC that can be done in $O(|G| \log |G|)$) so this is no improvement on your simple method of checking everything. Although, as others have pointed out, you only need to check that $a$ commutes with $n/2+1$ elements.